# How to use WebSockets in .NET core 2.0

Tags: .net-core

I found the WebSockets-Namespace in the .NET core documentation.
There is an abstract WebSocket class, I understand that I cannot instantiate this class directly, do I need to inherit the class and implement it by myself or is there a complete implementation somewhere else?

[Link to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocket?view=netcore-2.0)

I googled a lot, but everything I can find is for ASP.NET core.

Comment: How about this one: https://github.com/coinigy/PureWebSockets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft do provide a client implementation of the `WebSocket` class called [`ClientWebSocket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket?view=netcore-2.0).

You can find it as a NuGet package: [*System.Net.WebSockets.Client*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.WebSockets.Client/4.3.2/)

As far as I know, this is the only *official* and available implementation. If you need more than this, I do believe you have to find a 3rd party library or implement it yourself.